# windows multi-monitor system, map .net Screen to DirectX monitor #

Tags: .net, directx, obs

I will describe the need:

For bug-reporting purpose, we include in our application a way for video-capture of the screen.

For this purpose, we use an open source library called [OBS studio](https://obsproject.com/).

In a multi-monitor setup (virtually 100% of our customer base), we need to tell OBS which monitor to capture. OBS uses DirectX, which has a way to index the monitors, numbering them from 0.

Our application is a .net app. The 2 API calls that seem relevant are:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Screen.FromControl()
and
System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens
```

these static calls return a Screen object, or an array of screen objects ( [.NET docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.screen?view=netframework-4.5.2) ).

Now the question:

- How do I find the DirectX monitor number for the main window of my app (given the .net "Screen"), so I can ask OBS to record it?
- In other words, how do I map the AllScreens array from .NET, to monitor indexes understood by DirectX?

Peace.